# UV Map not being applied to object

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

Been going through old questions and tutorials for several hours and still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

My object unwraps fine in the UV Editor and I can add the file I want mapped, but it is not being applied in the 3D Viewer or when rendered.

[image]
[image]

The blue material was added to the object as some references said a material needed to be set before applying the UV Map.

Comment: The texture have to be applied in the material, what you have now is a texture that set to a brush

Comment: I have no idea how the brush got there or how replace it with material.

Answer (score 2):

To set up textures properly follow these steps:

**Cycles Render**

**1.** Select the material and open Node Editor window
**2.** Add an Image Texture node, then load the texture and connect Color to Diffuse BSDF node.
**3.** Add a UV Map node and select proper UV Map if you have more than one on the mesh and connect the node to the Vector of Image Texture node

[image]

**Blender Render**

**1.** Open materials tab.
**2.** Create a material or if there is one already existing, make sure the material you want to add the texture to is selected.

[image]

**3.** While the material is selected open texture tab.
**4.** In texture tab scroll down to Image section and open the texture you want to apply to the material.
**5.** In mapping section make sure the Coordinates are set to UV and choose the correct UV map in case you have more than one on the mesh.

[image]

Comment: Having the material selected before going to Texture controls is not adding a Material Icon or one for the object.. My Texture Editor looks different. No Mapping tab as in your step 5.

Comment: @Rivercoon I'm not sure what material icon you are talking about.

Comment: At the top of the last picture. Second row.
*Sphere *Material *Texture
I get *TexDraw and *Texture
Not sure how to add another picture in a comment.

Comment: @Rivercoon I think you are looking in the wrong place, I am talking about texture tab next to the material tab, not the UV/Image editor

Comment: See my first picture. It shows the Texture editor on the right. Midway up.

Comment: Oh, I just saw you are using Cycles. You have to use node editor to add a texture node and connect it to the diffuse node

Comment: Ah ha! That did it.  Never found mention of doing this elsewhere.  Thank you very much Denis!

Comment: @Rivercoon You are welcome, please accept it as an answer if you found it useful